# 403 error in website homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server, hosting

I am facing a problem with the homepage of http://www.personaleyes.com.au/. The site is made with WordPress. All other pages except the homepage have the status code of 200 but only the homepage has the error code of 403. FYI, the page opens as usual but SEO tools & Google WMT detect 403.

To find out the problem, I did the followings:

1. Deactivated and reactivated each of the WordPress plugins to find
   conflict (15 in total)
2. Checked permission. Folder permissions
   are set to 755 and file permissions to 644
3. Resetting the .htaccess
4. I downloaded the site and deployed in our server. When checked this
   homepage, it shows 200 as the status code
5. I have also disabled
   security plugin(wordfence security) to check as I found out in a
   forum that sometimes these plugins may cause this problem
6. Checked the site for corrupted files. Found out in a forum that the same error occurred because of a corrupted index.php file.

Any additional input on how to troubleshoot this problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at personaleyes.com.au and in your case it appears to be a .htaccess misconfiguration. Nothing appears to be wrong on the WordPress side of things as it is sending you a response and the page loads successfully.

Since .htaccess is recursive, do take a look at the parent directories of your WordPress installation too.